# Change text in TextView doesn't show more than three lines but on layout its shown correctly

Tags: android, string, android-layout, textview

I have a layout with a `TextView` that receives some text from a BBDD. When I write a long string on the layout, it shows everything correctly. When the same text is written by `texview.settext("sodjsdoifjsodfsd");`

I see that the `TextView` can only show the lines of this string.

I mean, it can change its dimension on the layout and I can see it correctly, with four or more lines if it is necessary, but when I change the text with a long string (as the string on the layout), I only see three lines of this text. I have the same problem with the text of the buttons.

I put a image, hope it helps:

[image]

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:text="Which ability of metal AM improves the osseointegrationdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddd capability and reduces surgical implants rejection rates?"
            android:textSize="20dp" />

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/HeaderTextView"
            android:paddingEnd="10dp"
            android:paddingStart="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp">


            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answer1"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:text="It doesn't need supports and allows to build in several levels"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answer2"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:text="ANSWER 2"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answer3"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:text="ANSWER 3"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/answer4"
                    android:layout_width="0dip"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:paddingRight="20dp"
                    android:text="ANSWER 4"
                    android:textSize="10dp" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/HeaderTextView2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="SEE ACRONYM BUTTON FOR MORE INFORMATION" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingStart="10dp">

            <TableRow
                android:id="@+id/tableRow6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="2dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/acronism"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:text="ACRONYM"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/explanation"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:padding="5dp"

                    android:background="@color/primary"
                    android:textColor="@color/accent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:text="Explanation"
                    android:textSize="20dp" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/PointsTextView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="POINTS:  "
            android:textAlignment="textEnd" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And the class code where I change the text:

```
header4questions.setText(listQuestions.get(questionPosition));
answer1.setText(listAnswers.get(questionPosition * 4));
answer2.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 1));
answer3.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 2));
answer4.setText(listAnswers.get((questionPosition * 4) + 3));
```

I don't know why it works perfectly on the layout but not with the android code.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There is a attribute called maxLines it goes like this

```
android:maxLines="2"
```

try that.

Comment: I try, wait please :)

Comment: can you share a screen shot of what is happening ?

Comment: I share a screenshot, any ideas? Thanks!